わかい とき and 子ども の とき. Why there are の after こども and not after わかい?

"わかい" とき、あまり べんきょうしませんでした。
"こどもの" とき、よく かわ で およぎました。

I know before とき any noun will marked by の and an adjective will marked by nothing(な adj will marked な). if わかい is an adjective こども should be an adj too. because "わかい とき" means "when I was young" and "こども とき" means "when I was kid". Then why there are の after こども and not after わかい?

Why would you think 子供 should be an adjective?

In those sentences, there is a similar fact. in those sentences "a period" is mentioned(1.when I was a kid 2.when I was young). if no "1" is a noun, no "2" should be a noun too, right?

OK, I see where you're coming from.  こども＋の acts as a "の-adjective".  The existing answers explain it well.  Also refer to the linked question.

We can understand what is going on grammatically simply by looking for the cues. わかい ends with い - this is not a guarantee, but a reason to suspect that it could be an i-adjective. If we look it up, we find that it is.
i-adjectives connect directly to nouns (such as とき).
But [子供]{こども} is a noun itself. There are compounds of multiple nouns in Japanese, but they're more specific exceptions rather than the rule.
Some nouns are also used as na-adjectives (or the other way around, if you prefer). But generally this doesn't happen with nouns that describe concrete, physical things (such as a child).
So, the default way to describe one noun using another, is to categorize it, by connecting it with の.
A [子供]{こども}の[時]{とき} is a time which is in the child category, i.e. a time that is associated with being a child, i.e. a time when the speaker was a child.
But a [若]{わか}い[時]{とき} is a time that, itself, is the thing that the 若 kanji describes. (Individual kanji aren't really words - even when a word is spelled using a single kanji and nothing else, the kanji itself is a distinct entity. But those entities do have a core meaning - they're ideographic characters.)
Now, individual Japanese words don't necessarily translate directly into individual English words, because of the different grammatical structure. We don't say "young time" or "youthful time" in English. But the general sense should be clear. And we do, or at least did, sometimes use adjectives like that in English (as any student of Shakespeare can tell you).

Neither 'kid' nor 'child' are adjectives in English but 'young' is (granted, English has a feature known as 'noun adjunct' that can make it difficult to tell - you can tell here because, while my kid brother is grammatical, when I was kid is not and it has to be when I was a kid). [若]{わか}い is an adjective and [子供]{こども} is a noun

In this case, 'こども' is not an adjective, but a noun. Therefore a 'の' is needed for after 'こども'
